# How change the http status codes with exception handling

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, http-status-codes

I'm trying to assign value to an with put controller which id is not already exists. Normally it should return 404  but it returns 500. How can I convert to 404?I'm try with if else but this is not working.

```
@PutMapping("/api/cricketer/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Cricketer> updateCricketer(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody @Valid Cricketer cricketer) {

    Cricketer cCricketer=cricketerService.findById(id);
    cCricketer.setId(id);
    cCricketer.setCountry(cricketer.getCountry());
    cCricketer.setName(cricketer.getName());
    cCricketer.setHighestScore(cricketer.getHighestScore());
    cricketerRepository.save(cCricketer);
    if (cCricketer.getId()!=null){
        return new ResponseEntity<Cricketer>(cCricketer,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your title contains "exception handling" yet I don't see any exception handling in your code. Do you know how exceptions are handled in the first place?

Comment: you might be getting some exception.. check what it is, and whether you need to catch it

Comment: if `id` is not found it will throw `500`,  use like this `try{Cricketer cCricketer=cricketerService.findById(id);}catch(Exception e){ return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);}` (not a good solution tho)

Comment: I don't think you'll ever hit your `else` statement.  If your `cricketerService.findById` throws exceptions if it can't find the `Cricketer`, then you won't hit it.  If the same method returns `null` you'll get a `NullPointerException` and won't hit it.  And if it returns _some_ `Cricketer`, then you set the id in the next line of code, so `cCricketer.getId()` would _not_ be `null` and you won't hit it.

Comment: Can you please confirm that execution reaches the line where you are returning 404 and there is no exception thrown from controller?

Comment: HTTP 404 is not used for this purpose. Your case, your server application met an error ,where particular data was not found . This is internal server error 500. 404 is meant for reporting the URL was not pointing to an available resource. So 404 should be handled only in such conditions.

Comment: @Kris: That's really not true...  `404` is _often_ used to indicate 'resource not found', in this case the resource being the `Cricketer`.

Comment: @user2478398 The case of update, for an unavailable resource - is it an error or Not Found ?

Comment: It is a client error...  They have tried to update something that doesn't exist.  So 5xx doesn't make sense.  And I would say of the 4xx codes, 404 NOT FOUND is definitely the best fit.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of options.

---

Have `CricketerService` throw an `Exception` (probably domain specific `CricketerNotFoundException` or something similar) on the `findById` method, and add an `@ExceptionHandler` for that.

```
@ExceptionHandler(CricketerNotFoundException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
private void handleCricketerNotFoundException(final CricketerNotFoundException cnfEx) {
    // Log, do anything else...
}
```

(You could also add `@ResponseStatus` on the `CricketerNotFoundException` class itself.)

---

Have `CricketerService.findById` return `null` if it can't find it and *handle* that case:

```
public ResponseEntity<Cricketer> updateCricketer(
        @PathVariable("id") Long id, 
        @RequestBody @Valid Cricketer cricketer) {

    @Nullable Cricketer cCricketer=cricketerService.findById(id);

    if (cricketer == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    cCricketer.setId(id);
    cCricketer.setCountry(cricketer.getCountry());
    cCricketer.setName(cricketer.getName());
    cCricketer.setHighestScore(cricketer.getHighestScore());
    cricketerRepository.save(cCricketer);

    return new ResponseEntity<Cricketer>(cCricketer, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```